# SegFault in Cache Sim C program

Tags: c, caching, segmentation-fault

EDIT: so it's easier for you guys to find where in my code I think the segfault is happening, look under the commented section called `/* Cache Structure */`

EDIT2: made a huge mistake with gdb the correct output when it segfaults from gdb is:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /.autofs/ilab/ilab_users/petejodo/Assignment4/a.out 
1
/.autofs/ilab/ilab_users/petejodo/Assignment4/a.out

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00449453 in strlen () from /lib/libc.so.6
(gdb)
```

EDIT3: after resorting to n00b tactics like printing lines, I've found it prints before:

```
file = fopen(purefile, "r");
    if (file == 0){
        printf ("Could not find file!\n");
        return 0;
    }
```

but doesnt print "test" I have underneath it.

ORIGINAL

So after checking all the threads on segfault and using gdb I can't figure out why my program is segfaulting at this line. I'm writing a cache simulator (only have write-through in my code currently) and I didn't include my methods because they are fine, it's in the main method.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    FILE* file;

    /* Counter variables */
    int i;
    int j;

    /* Helper Variables */
    int setAdd;
    int totalSet;
    int trash;
    int size;
    int extra;
    char rw;

    /* Necessary Character Arrays */
    char hex[100];
    char bin[100];
    char origTag[100];
    char bbits[100];
    char sbits[100];
    char tbits[100];

    /* Cache Info Variables */
    int setNumber = 4096; /* cacheSize/blockSize : (16,384/4) */
    int setBits = 12; /* log(setNumber)/log(2) : (log(4096)/log(2)) */
    int tagSize = 18; /* 32-(blockBits + setBits) **blockBits = log(blockSize)/log(2)** : (32 - (2 + 12) */

    /* Results */
    int cacheHit = 0;
    int cacheMiss = 0;
    int write = 0;
    int read = 0;

    /* Cache Structure */
    tempLine cache[4096];

    char* style;
    char* purefile;
    if (strcmp(argv[1], "-h")==0) 
    {
        puts("Usage: sim <write policy> <trace file>");
        return 0;
    } 
    style = argv[1];
    purefile = argv[2];
    file = fopen(purefile, "r");/* HYPOTHESIZED SEGFAULT HERE */
    if (file == 0){
        printf ("Could not find file!\n");
        return 0;
    }
    printf("test1");
    /* Setting Structure Default Values */
    for(i = 0; i < setNumber; i++)
    {
        cache[i].tag = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(tagSize + 1));
        for(j = 0; j < tagSize; j++)
        {
            cache[i].tag[j] = '0';
        }
        cache[i].valid = 0;
    }

    /* Main Loop */
    while(fgetc(file) != '#')
    {
        setAdd = 0;
        totalSet = 0;

        fseek(file, -1, SEEK_CUR);
        fscanf(file, "%d: %c %s\n", &trash, &rw, origTag);

        /* Cutting off '0x' off from address '0x00000000' and adding 0's if necessary */
        size = strlen(origTag);
        extra = (10 - size);
        for(i = 0; i < extra; i++)
            hex[i] = '0';
        for(i = extra, j = 0; i < (size-(2-extra)); i++, j++)
            hex[i] = origTag[j + 2];

        hex[8] = '\0';

        hex2bin(hex, bin);

        split(bin, bbits, sbits, tbits);

        /* Changing cArray into int */
        for(i = 0, j = (setBits - 1); i < setBits; i++, j--)
        {
            if (sbits[i] == '1')
                setAdd = 1;
            if (sbits[i] == '0')
                setAdd = 0;
            setAdd = setAdd * pow(2, j);
            totalSet += setAdd;
        }

        /* Calculating Hits and Misses */
        if (cache[totalSet].valid == 0)
        {
            cache[totalSet].valid = 1;
            strcpy(cache[totalSet].tag, tbits);
        }

        if ((cache[totalSet].valid == 1) && (strcmp(cache[totalSet].tag, tbits) == 0))
        {
            /* HIT */
            if (rw == 'W')
            {
                cacheHit++;        
                write++;
            }
            if (rw == 'R')
                cacheHit++;    
         }
         else
         {
             /* MISS */
            if (rw == 'R')
            {
                cacheMiss++;
                read++;
            }
            if (rw == 'W')
            {
                cacheMiss++;
                read++;
                write++;
            }
            cache[totalSet].valid = 1;
            strcpy(cache[totalSet].tag, tbits);
        }
        /* End Calculations */  
    }
    printResult(cacheHit, cacheMiss, read, write);

    return 0;
}
```

And what I got out of gdb was this:

```
**INCORRECT**

(gdb) run
Starting program: /.autofs/ilab/ilab_users/petejodo/Assignment4/a.out 

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x080489b6 in main (argc=1, argv=0xbfffe954) at sim.c:128
128             if (strcmp(argv[1], "-h")==0)
(gdb) bt

#0  0x080489b6 in main (argc=1, argv=0xbfffe954) at sim.c:128
```

I'm kind of lost, any help would be great. Thanks!

Oh, and also checking the value of `argv[1]` it is `NULL` or `0x0` because I think it is because of that. `argv[1]` is supposed to contain either the help flag or write through or write back, I just haven't coded in whether to check for write through or write back just yet.

Answer (score 1):

You need to test if `argc > 1` if you want to access `argv[1]`. A program always receives the name it was called by (e.g. `./a.out` in your case) as `argv[0]`, so `argc >= 1` is always true. To access the first real argument - i.e. the second element of `argv` - you need to test if there are at least *two* arguments. However, testing if there are `> n` elements when accessing `argv[n]` is more readable IMO since both numbers are the same.

Here's an example on how to change your code:

```
if (argc < 3 || (argv > 1 && strcmp(argv[1], "-h")==0))
{
    puts("Usage: sim <write policy> <trace file>");
    return 0;
}
```

In this case you will show an error if there are not enough arguments provided to have valid `argv[1]` and `argv[2]` elements or if the first argument is `-h` (in case someone puts stuff after `-h` - otherwise it'd be handled by the too-few-arguments check).

You should have a look at [`getopt()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getopt) by the way - it makes argument/switch parsing much easier and cleaner.

Comment: I should also add that it doesn't segfault when I use the -h flag only when I use a different flag is when it segfaults. I still get a segfault using your code too btw. I will look into getopt() though

Comment: When you use `-h` you exit before accessing `argv[1]`; when using a different flag you access an invalid array element so BOOM. If the program still breaks with my code, there might be something else going wrong - impossible to tell without seeing the message/line from GDB.

Comment: Then what would be my next course of action?  EDIT: btw I tried printing out all the arguments and that works fine as well